# Unity - How do I apply an animation from one game object to another rigged game object?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am thinking of building a game like the sims and was thinking of how I could make the characters interact with any object without having to systematically change the character's code and prefab whenever I decide to add new furniture and props to the library. I have had an idea that consists of having my animations attached to the furniture itself rather than having it attached to the character (which would require a lot of memory and extra code if we had a lot of furniture in the game library!). I was thinking about it and had in mind that I could add a rig skeleton in Blender that has the desired animation(s) but not rig any specific object - so that I only have the animation, the location, rotation and scale of the bones! and since the characters' rigs are the same as the skeleton's rig in the furniture's animation, they could be compatible! 
I hope this makes sense... 
The thing is that I realise at this stage that I do not know the Animation class very well, and **I am not sure if / how I can use the animation attached to the furniture to make my character interact with it...** 
Can Animation.Play() take multiple arguments apart from the animation to play and the play mode? Is it possible to specify which object has to play the animation? I am talking about doing all of this **from the script** - I write in C# by the way... and I might attach the script to the camera so I hope the script does not have to be necessarily attached to the character prefab in order to play the animation... Though I don't mind creating a function in the character's script if necessary!

I am not new to Unity but I have mostly been using cars and character controllers, so I haven't dealt with much animation coding yet... 
I thank you in advance for your help and apologise for my weird english - I live in France! ^^

Comment: look in the scripting reference for the Animation class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mecanim performs [retargeting](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html) of humanoid animations, so for what concern that specific case, you should be able to use the same rig and set of animation clip on different models.

For what concern grabbing furniture, you don't need the object to be rigged. You can use [IK](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) to precise move your character's hand toward the target object and then parent it to the relative joint in the hierarchy.

Comment: If I wanted to do this from the script (applying animations attached to the furniture to my character), could I just do:
'Animation.Play(furniture.interactAnimation);' from the character's script, assuming there is a Furniture class and that we have set an instance of that class depending on the furniture the character is interacting with?

Comment: What do you mean with "animations attached to the furniture to my character"? Typically it's the character that is rigged and animated. Furniture is somewhat static, if you want to grab you simply can attach it to the hand joint for example.

Comment: What I was hoping was to insert an animated humanoid rig inside the furniture prefab so that if the character was to interact with it, the character would play the animation stored inside the furniture prefab.

Comment: Suppose the character had to perform tasks such as turning the tv on or opening a drawer. I think if i store the animation on the character prefab, i won`t be able to make him interact as smoothly and accurately with the furniture and objects as if the rig was contained inside the furniture/ object's prefab.